# Scaffold API controller using Postgres

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to avoid rewriting or copy/paste always the same boilerplate code to create a new API Controller on VS Mac starting from an entity. I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#scaffold-a-controller) in which Microsoft explain how to do it using command line (VS Mac/VS Code cases) but if I try to execute the command an error is returned:

```
enrico@Enricos-MBP MyApi % dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MarkersController -async -api -m Markers -dc myContext -outDir Controllers
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
To scaffold, install the following Entity Framework core packages and try again: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:04.60
```

`aspnet-codegenerator` ask me to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` but in this specific case I'm using `PostgreSQL`.

Is there any way to do it using Postgres DB?

Comment: Post your DbContext configuration and registration code. Did you specify the SQL Server provider by mistake perhaps? Have you added a PostgreSQL provider? The article you linked to doesn't use the SQL Server provider so it doesn't require this package.

Comment: Yes, I'm correctly importing `Npgsql` using `UseNpgsql`. My API is already on prod and it is working well. You are right about SQL Server Provider, anyway I found the solution simply using VS Mac, don't know why Microsoft does not use this simply method

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that there is a scaffolding wizard also on VS Mac (I don't know why Microsoft does not explain that).

To scaffold a controller starting from an entity you need to:

1. Right click on `Controller` folder of your project
2. Add --> `New Scaffolding`
3. Select `API Controller with actions using Entity Framework`
4. Select your Db Model and Db Context from the combobox
5. Assign your Controller Name

**P.S.**
This procedure create correctly the controller but it install two new packages:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.10" />
```

I don't know why they are needed because as explained I'm already importing the dedicated Postgres NuGet package

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.4" />
```